# how to sum values in access with repeating unique keys

Tags: ms-access

I am new to access. I an trying to add the values together so that each unique key (on the left) corresponds to a single value sum from the three cities.

I have tried using sum function and totals in query design, didn't work and gave error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, ignoring column 3:

```sql
Select [Column1], Sum([Column2]) As Total
From YourTable
Group By [Column1]
```